# TextWatcher on two edittexts

Tags: android

I have two edittexts, and I want change one while I  text on another and vice-versa. I used TextWatcher, and it got more or less like this:

```
 //MUDAR AO DIGITAR
        edt1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //quando o texto é alterado chamamos o filtro.
                double valor = (s.length()>0)?Double.parseDouble(s.toString()):0;
                valor = (valor * 100);
                edt2.setText(valor);
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {}
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        });

        edt2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                double valor = (s.length()>0)?Double.parseDouble(s.toString()):0;
                valor = (valor / 100);
                edt1.setText(valor);
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {}
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        });
```

But This code not work, only works with one and I need both

Comment: Shoudn't the code inside listener be equal with the exception of `edit?.setText(valor)`. Why do you `valor = (valor / 100);` instead of `valor = (valor * 100);`  ?

Comment: Probabily yes, but the error is not this, the changing is not work independent of value or setText method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have set textChangeListener on both edit text and and setting text on both call back events(onTextChangeListener) it will be infinite iteration. It will keep setting text on edittext of one side and call back will be keep calling. Hence this cycle will keep running untill app gets crashed. 
**Edit**
To achieve what you want see  below details

**You need to keep track currently on what edit text you have focus(This is for setting text in edit text). You need to have 2 boolean variables. Now see below code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText edt1, edt2;
boolean et1Focus, et2Focus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edt1 = findViewById(R.id.et1);
    edt2 = findViewById(R.id.et2);

            edt1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //quando o texto é alterado chamamos o filtro.
            if (et1Focus) {
                double valor = (s.length() > 0) ? Double.parseDouble(s.toString()) : 0;
                valor = (valor * 100);
                edt2.setText(String.valueOf(valor));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

    edt2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (et2Focus) {
                double valor = (s.length() > 0) ? Double.parseDouble(s.toString()) : 0;
                valor = (valor / 100);
                edt1.setText(String.valueOf(valor));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

    edt1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            et1Focus = b;
        }
    });

    edt2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            et2Focus = b;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Hope that helps ..If you have any question feel free to ask

Comment: I see where you' re coming from, but why is the app not crashing now ?

Comment: Sooner or later it will hang your cell phone. due to continously setting this cycle. You can try the same code and see what happens

Comment: Exist some way to do this? withou crash or hang the phone

Comment: :) I am glad that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

//try this code call initViews in OnCreate Method.

```
EditText edt1, edt2;

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt1);
            edt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt2);
            edt1.requestFocus();
            edt1.addTextChangedListener(this);
            edt1.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }




        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable)
        {
            if (editable == edt1.getEditableText())
            {

            }
            else if (editable == edt2.getEditableText())
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: I tryed this, but is not possible call this methods insides onCreate

Comment: i have edited my answer it will work according to your need.

Comment: I do exactly what you said, and put edt2.sextText inside first IF. Return this error:  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   java.lang.StackOverflowError
                                                       at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1747)
                                                       at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:185)

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem when trying to create a currency converter app. (Change value in editText 1 should change the value in editText 2 and vice versa).

The way I got around it was to create two text watchers.

```
private TextWatcher TextWatcherClass = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                              int count) {
        editText2.removeTextChangedListener(TextWatcherClass2);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        editText2.addTextChangedListener(TextWatcherClass2);
    }

};

private TextWatcher TextWatcherClass2 = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                              int count) {
        editText1.removeTextChangedListener(TextWatcherClass);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        editText1.addTextChangedListener(TextWatcherClass);
    }

};
```

Hope this helps.